# How do I check for "Test Email" in the subject?

Tags: vba, outlook, rules, case-sensitive

I tried to set a rule in Outlook only to learn that rules are not case-sensitive.

I want if an email is received and the subject includes "Test Email" (like This is a Test Email), then check the body.
If the body contains the word NO, in capital letters (not a part of a word), then move the email to a specific folder.

I found the below script for incoming emails that contain NO in the body.

How do I first check for "Test Email" in the title?

```vb
Private WithEvents InboxItems As Outlook.Items
Private m_Rules As Variant
    
Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim i As Long
    i = -1: ReDim m_Rules(1000)
    i = i + 1: m_Rules(i) = Array("NO", "No Folder")
    ReDim Preserve m_Rules(i)
    Set InboxItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub
    
Private Sub InboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim i As Long, Find As String
    'Find = Item.Subject
    Find = Item.Body
    For i = 0 To UBound(m_Rules)
        If InStr(1, Find, m_Rules(i)(0), vbBinaryCompare) Then
            Set Folder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
            Set Folder = Folder.Folders(m_Rules(i)(1))
            Item.Move Folder
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The *title* that you refer to is the *Subject*. You seem to know how to use `InStr` in the *Body*. I'm not sure why you can't use it in the *Subject* as well.

Comment: So I tried changing it to look for subject - figured I would start with that - and I thought it would be checking all email as it hits the inbox but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I'm not sure how to add my code into this comment field, sorry :(

Comment: You don't add your code into the comment field. You [edit] your post to put it into the question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Regex search function which I use to filter received e-mail. Should be editable to what you desire

> In ThisOutlookSession

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call RegExFilterRules(EntryIDCollection)
End Sub
```

> In a module

```
Sub RegExFilterRules(ItemID As String)
    Dim ThisNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace: Set ThisNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Inbox = ThisNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Dim Junk As Outlook.MAPIFolder: Set Junk = ThisNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderJunk)
    
    Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem: Set oMsg = ThisNamespace.GetItemFromID(ItemID, Inbox.StoreID)
    
    If Not oMsg Is Nothing And oMsg.Class = olMail Then
        If FindPattern(oMsg.Subject, "^M\d+$") Then oMsg.Move Junk ' oMsg.Delete
    End If
End Sub

Private Function FindPattern(Str As String, Pattern As String) As Boolean
    ' Requires Reference: Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim RegEx As Object: Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = Pattern
        FindPattern = .Test(Str)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try and see how I go. Learning all about this so appreciate the help and I will try to follow and understand your code :)